# Tic Tac Toe Programming help C++

Tags: c++

My main questions are, how do I get the tokens (X's and O's) to appear on the game board? I have to ask the user for the row number and column number and the token will be placed there. As you may be able to tell, I am new to programming. I have been at this for hours and I just would like to be done. Asking on here is my last resort. If any of the code could be done differently or more efficiently or isn't necessary or if I did something wrong, please let me know. I am out of ideas. I just would like to finish this program, so the more detailed you could be, the better. I greatly appreciate it. I am confused and really need advice to finish this.

my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void createBoard(int board[][3], char charBoard[][3]);
void printBoard(char charBoard[][3]);
int checkWinner (int board[][3], int player);
bool checkMove(int board[][3], int row, int column);
void resetBoard(int board[][3]);

int main ()
{
    int board[3][3];
    char charBoard[3][3];
    int player;
    int row, column;
    bool win = false;
    char again = 'y';

    while (win == false)
    {
        createBoard(board, charBoard);
        printBoard(charBoard);
        cout << "Player O's turn!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter row number: "; cin >> row;
        cout << "Enter column number: "; cin >> column;
        checkMove(board, row, column);
        //update board
        win = checkWinner(board, -1);
        if (checkWinner (board, -1)  == true)
        {
            cout << "Player O wins!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        //set flag to denote it's x's turn
        printBoard(charBoard);
        cout << "Player X's turn!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter row number: "; cin >> row;
        cout << "Enter column number: "; cin >> column;
        checkMove(board, row, column);
        //update board
        win = checkWinner (board, 1);
        if (checkWinner (board, 1) == true)
        {
            cout << "Player X wins!" << endl;
            break;
        }


        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n): ";
        cin >> again;

        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Good bye!" << endl;

        return 0;
}



void createBoard(int board[][3], char charBoard[][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            // if game board has a -1, put an "O" in the character board
            if (board[i][j]== -1)
            {
                charBoard[i][j] = 'O';
            }
            // if game board has a 1, put an "X" in the character board
            else if (board[i][j]== 1)
            {
                charBoard[i][j] = 'X';
            }
            // if game board has a 0, put an " " (blank space) in the character board
            else
            {
                charBoard[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}

void printBoard(char charBoard[][3])
{
    cout << "       Tic Tac Toe!" << endl << endl;
    cout << "          Column\n";
    cout << "       0     1     2" << endl << endl;
    cout << "R 0    " << charBoard[0][0] << "  |  " << charBoard[0][1] << "  |  " << charBoard[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "    --------------------" << endl;
    cout << "O 1    " << charBoard[1][0] << "  |  " << charBoard[1][1] << "  |  " << charBoard[1][2] << endl;
    cout << "    --------------------" << endl;
    cout << "W 2    " << charBoard[2][0] << "  |  " << charBoard[2][1] << "  |  " << charBoard[2][2] << endl << endl;
}

int checkWinner (int board[][3], int player)
{
    int sum;

    // Check each column for a winner
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sum = board[i][0] + board[i][1] + board[i][2];
        // if O is a winner
        if (sum == 3*player)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Check each row for a winner
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        sum = board[0][j] + board[1][j] + board[2][j];
        // if O is a winner
        if (sum == 3*player)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Check the back and front diagonal
    sum = board[0][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][2];
    if (sum == 3*player)
    {
        return true;
    }

    sum = board[0][2] + board[1][1] + board[2][0];
    if (sum == 3*player)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool checkMove(int board[][3], int row, int column)
{
    if ((row < 0) || (row > 2))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if ((column < 0) || (column > 2))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (board[row][column] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void resetBoard(int board[][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm considering your question, but it should be mentioned that `if (checkWinner (board, 1) == true)` is redundant, `if (checkWinner (board, 1))` will do the same thing.

Comment: I think you have other problems. It seems that after a player wins, the code exits, and after each turn (before someone wins) they are asked if they want to play again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should insert the appropriate value in the 'checkMove' function:

```
else if (board[row][column] == 0)
{
    board[row][column] = value;    // value -1 or 1
    return true;
}
```

Where 'value' is either -1 or 1 depending on if you are inserting an X or an O. The function as it is doesn't have any information on who is adding the mark, so you may add another parameter to the function to pass in 'value'.